# Paypal dynamic value in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, frontend, paypal-sandbox

I need help with my project I want to add a dynamic option to the PayPal payment process. ( change the value to be dynamic )

the default option is value: '0.01' and the dynamic payment in my project is cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol

I try to add [const {amount} = cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol;] this line to try to change the value to value: amount but this is not working for me.

thanks for help

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import CartItem from './CartItem';

const PayPalButton = window.paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });

// paypal payment buttons
    const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
        const {amount} = cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol;
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [
            {
              amount: {
                  value: amount,
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      }

      const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture();
      }
      
onst FilledCart = () => (
        <>
            <div>
                {cart.line_items.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <CartItem item={item} handleUpdateCratQty={handleUpdateCratQty} handleRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={handleEmptyCart}>EmptyCart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [react-paypal-js documentation](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default) is straightforward enough...

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
    PayPalScriptProvider,
    PayPalButtons,
    usePayPalScriptReducer
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

// This values are the props in the UI
const amount = "2";
const currency = "USD";
const style = {"layout":"vertical"};

// Custom component to wrap the PayPalButtons and handle currency changes
const ButtonWrapper = ({ currency, showSpinner }) => {
    // usePayPalScriptReducer can be use only inside children of PayPalScriptProviders
    // This is the main reason to wrap the PayPalButtons in a new component
    const [{ options, isPending }, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: "resetOptions",
            value: {
                ...options,
                currency: currency,
            },
        });
    }, [currency, showSpinner]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i still dont get it your question, but if you want to change your value maybe u can try using react hook (useState), or maybe u can provide what is inside object `cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol` ?

Comment: I am using Commerce.js so this cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol line comes from Commerce.js this is the subtotal of all products in the cart. But I don't know how to change the value in PayPal to be dynamic (I mean with the same subtotal).